# Resize evenly by taking the available space?

Tags: inkscape

I have 4 rectangles:

[image]

How can I make the bottom ones (2,3 and 4) to take all the width provided by *Rectangle1* equally?

I.e. rectangles 2, 3 and 4 must have the same size but I'd like to have no spacing in between them, and also I'd like *Rectangle2* to start where *Rectangle1* starts, and *Rectangle4* to end where *Rectangle1* ends.

Comment: So are you asking us how to divide by 3, how to measure a distance, how to scale from a point or something else?

Comment: Let me clear this up a bit, see the update.

Comment: Divide the width of first rectangle by 3 and duplicate it 3 times?

Comment: That can work, yes, but is not there any function in Inkscape which doesn't involve an external calculator? :)

Comment: Most design applications actually accept arithmetic functions in input boxes. No inkscape in front of me but try typing /3 in the width input.

Comment: @Daniel - yes you can do simple arithmetic inside the height/width fields.

Comment: By the way i have often wondered why do not all applications accept stuff like this by defaul. After all whats the point of forcing me to jump to another box when even stupidest application platforms can implement this with no effort. After all computers are calculators whats the point of me calculating something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the arithmetic in the width field in Inkscape.

Duplicate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the long rectangle, click and drag downwards while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain the move vertically, then type `/3` after the width value to divide by 3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

Duplicate the resized piece, and move into position while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain the move horizontally. Use snapping if you want things to line up. Repeat for the last piece.

An example

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For something as simple as this, you don't even need to use arithmetic. Just take advantage of snapping.

- Draw a rectangle with random dimensions.
- Duplicate it two times and snap the three rectangles tightly together.
- Snap the three rectangles to one of the corners of the original rectangle.
- Scale the three rectangles to the same dimensions as the original rectangle.
- Move the three rectangles to the desired position.

[image]